# Активные ссылки в меню Opencart 2

Tags: php, opencart

Доброго дня. Есть вопрос насчет opencart 2. Вывел в верхнее меню вместо категорий, ссылки на страницы, а также ссылку на страницу с производителями. Суть вопроса. Как присвоить ссылке класс active при нахождении на странице с производителями?

Попробовал по аналогии с модулем категории, но что-то не хочет работать.

```
   <?php if ($manufacturer['manufacturer_id'] == $manufacturer_id) { ?>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $manufacturer; ?>" class="new_class"><?php echo $text_manufacturer; ?></a></li>
       <?php } else { ?>
       <li><a href="<?php echo $manufacturer; ?>"><?php echo $text_manufacturer; ?></a></li>
       <?php } ?>
```

Был бы весьма благодарен, если бы помогли разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, для решения этой задачи лучше воспользоваться js. Добавьте в **footer.tpl** (не забудьте вызвать функцию):

```
function hightlightNav(){
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
    path = decodeURIComponent(path);
    $(".nav > li").each(function () {
        var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        if (href.indexOf(path) > 0) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
}
```

Функция переберёт линки по условию и добавит класс **active** найденому.

Я писал в соответствии с html-разметкой своего шаблона, но у вас должно быть похоже. Решение накладывает определённые ограничения по условию поиска ($(".nav > li")), поэтому следите за разметкой.